# How do I apply multiple conditions to create new variable from current variables in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, mean

I am trying to apply multiple conditions to current variables to create a new variable. I am looking at 5 variables/columns and want to apply the following conditions. If 3 out of the 5 variables are >0, take the mean of only of variables that are >0. If <3 variables are >0 then NA

For example,

| ID | Work | School | School 2 | Work 1 | Work 2 | New Variable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | -2 | -1 | -7 | 2 | NA |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | -1 | 2 | 3 | 3.25 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3.2 |
| 4 | -1 | 2 | -7 | 2 | 4 | 2.67 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df[["New Variable"]] <- apply(df[, -1], 1, function(row) {
  if (sum(row > 0) >= 3) mean(row[row > 0]) else NA
})
```

`df[, -1]` is to ignore first column (`ID`)

---

Where `df` is:

```
df <- read.table(text = 
'ID Work    School  "School 2"  "Work 1"    "Work 2"
1   5   -2  -1  -7  2
2   3   5   -1  2   3
3   4   5   1   3   3
4   -1  2   -7  2   4
', header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for  your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using a vectorized solution where we create a logical matrix (`i1`), then create a logical vector with `rowSums` and use `ifelse` to return the `mean` of only those have greater than or equal to 3 positive values by changing the other elements to NA and making use of `na.rm` argument

```
i1 <- df[-1] > 0
df$New <- ifelse(rowSums(i1) >= 3, rowMeans(replace(df[-1],
       !i1, NA), na.rm = TRUE), NA)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Work = c(5L, 3L, 4L, -1L), School = c(-2L, 
5L, 5L, 2L), `School 2` = c(-1L, -1L, 1L, -7L), `Work 1` = c(-7L, 
2L, 3L, 2L), `Work 2` = c(2L, 3L, 3L, 4L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```